# I am a getting a gradle error for the war closure in build.gradle file

Tags: gradle

I am getting the following error for the following war block in the build.gradle file:

```
war {
    from file("${buildDir}/pad.checkpoint")
    archiveBaseName = 'x'
    archiveFileName 'x.war'
    manifest {
        attributes("Implementation-Title": "X",
                "Implementation-Version": "${checkpoint_version}") //CHANGED: using checkpoint version, 4/29/2019
    }
}

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':x'.
> No signature of method: build_bwabkxkz50kzi9n1i5g4tpde.war() is applicable for argument types: (build_bwabkxkz50kzi9n1i5g4tpde$_run_closure7) values: [build_bwabkxkz50kzi9n1i5g4tpde$_run_closure7@459c6649]
  Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), tap(groovy.lang.Closure), run(), run(), any()
```

It was working before with the deprecated variables baseName and archiveName. I think it is happening because the war closure hasn't been set for receiving the new upgraded variables.

Spring boot version being used:  springBootVers = '2.2.6.RELEASE'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, errors when using the Groovy DSL can sometimes be swallowed in these generic MissingMethodException" problems. It means that something inside the closure couldn't be resolved. I find that the easiest way to figure out what is wrong is to comment out code until the closure can be resolved.

In your case, it is the line `archiveFileName 'x.war'`. In groovy, parenthesis are (sometimes) optional, so this is equivalent to `archiveFileName('x.war')`.

However, as you can see from the [War API documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War), `archiveBaseName` is a property and not a method. So to fix it, change it to an assignment instead: `archiveFileName = 'x.war'`.

You will most likely not need both `archiveBaseName` and `archiveFileName` at the same time though.

Comment: Will that serve the same purpose?

Comment: If your goal is to name the resulting artifact 'x.war', then yes, `archiveFileName = 'x.war'` will do that. But if you are using Spring Boot, shouldn't you be using the `bootWar`task?

Comment: Can we have a chat conversation?

Comment: It works for me 
Thanks